# Rerender doesn't work for pageBlockTable. How can I make it work?

Tags: rerender

I have a table of records and I need to rerender the table when a record is deleted. The delete function works fine but it doesn't rerender the table.

```
<apex:pageblock title="Record" id="records_block">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!records}" var="record">
        <apex:column>
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRecord}" reRender="records_block">
                <apex:param name="recordId" value="{!record.Id}" assignTo="{!recordId}" />
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!record.Date__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!record.Type__c}" />
    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>

public String recordId { get; set {recordId = value;} }
public void deleteRecord() {
    Record__c record = [SELECT Id FROM Record__c WHERE Id=:recordId];
    delete record;
}
```

Comment: I have answered .If this does not fix ,share your whole code and we will get it fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have used get set on your list .The list that renders or displays table still holds the previous values cached and hence you are not getting actual results.

> You may like to again re query whole list back and populate your getter for correct result .